# How to put Three imageview buttons on same line in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-layout

I have three **imageViews** There I want to set all these `ImageView` into one line. I have pasted my current xml code below.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFragement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="306dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.77"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </RelativeLayout>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/login_button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:src="@drawable/login_non_click" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comapre_now_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/compare_now_non_click_state" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comapre_now_button"
        android:src="@drawable/search_non_click" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**After i have sloved. posted my App's image i think this is helpful all**
[image: After editing i have posted my App's image i think this is helpful]

After editing i have posted my App's all Xml code i think this is helpful all.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myFragement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="306dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.77"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >
     <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/login_button"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

             android:src="@drawable/login_non_click" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comapre_now_button"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/compare_now_non_click_state" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/search_non_click" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer that fida gave should provide what you want (or close to it). That is assuming that you want them all to take up 1/3 of the screen. Otherwise, you can eliminate the `weight` property and use margin between the `View`s or use empty `View`s between each of them and give an appropriate `weight`.

The reason you aren't getting them in a horizontal layout is because you have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for the first `ImageView` so I'm guessing that is taking up the whole width. They should probably be `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. Also, for your last one, you have `android:layout_below="@+id/comapre_now_button"` which will obviously put it below the `View` with that `id`.

Assuming you want that in the center, you probably want `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` or `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/someId"` or `android:layout_toLeftOf="id/someId"`

Also, not the problem, but `RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` or `weight` property.

Comment: @VenushkaT it was obvious by looking at your code how it may look but these types of questions are usually better answered when you can explain what you are getting versus what you want. Also, images are always helpful.

Comment: thank you for your advice.its really helpful to others.next time i will do it

Comment: No problem. It was a good question other than you didn't specify what your current result is. So just keep that in mind.

Comment: your correct. i have posted my app's view. in between imageView buttons there are white spaces are there any way to avoid these white spaces.Thank you

Comment: There are definitely ways to avoid it but I don't know what code you are using to get this result. If you edit and add (not replace the current code) I can look and see why.

Comment: here im developing custom tabhost using fragements for that i used three imageViews.thank you

Comment: Ok, but I don't know what the xml is that is giving you the current result. The answer by fida should give you them side-by-side

Comment: could you please find my edited code.there i have posted my edited xml code.thank you.are there any way to avoid white spaces.25 % of Screen s there are white spaces.thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Try like below, put the `ImageView`s in an inner `LinearLayout` with horizontal `orientation`:

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/login_non_click" />
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/comapre_now_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/compare_now_non_click_state" />
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/search_non_click" />   
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It worked for me too with a little change: I made a LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation (as you said) within my LinearLayout with Vertial orientation. I am not sure if it is the most straightforward way, but it works quit fine!